# How to plot a commuting graph of dihedral group using GAP?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, gap

I'm studying commuting graphs in dihedral group using **GAP**. Does someone know a good way to plot a commuting graph using GAP (the vertex are the elements of the group and they are joined iff $x*y=y*x$). I can do it to groups with a small order manually, but when it comes to greater order, like D32, it's difficult to make the graph symmetric, for example. I'd be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you spell out more where your problem lies? Is it to obtain the full adjacency relation, or is it in plotting a graph for a givven adjacency relation?